# JDBI useHandle waiting for completing transaction from another handler

Tags: jdbi, jdbi3

I have an import method. First, a session record is created in the database. Then comes the import process, wrapped in a transaction.

```
   private void importTables(File sessionRootDirectory, UUID sessionId, ImportResult result) {
    asyncJdbi.useTransaction(handle -> {
        try {
            sessionService.updateSession(sessionId, EiSessionStatus.RUNNING);
            String rootPath = sessionRootDirectory.getPath();
            ImportContext importContext = new ImportContext(rootPath, handle, result, sessionId);
            if (importContext.getTotalImportFilesCount() > 0) {
                processTables(importContext);
            } else {
                updateStatisticForEmptyArchive(importContext);
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException | IOException e) {
            result.setHasErrors(true);
            handle.rollback();
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            cleanTempTables(handle);
            FileUtils.deleteQuietly(sessionRootDirectory);
        }
    });
}
```

And at the same time, I need to update some session parameters as the import progresses
**(sessionService.updateSession(sessionId, EiSessionStatus.RUNNING)**;.

I'm using one instance of JDBI for transaction and updating session in db. This is method to update session

```
public void updateSession(UUID sessionId, EiSessionStatus status) {
    asyncJdbi.useHandle(handle -> handle.attach(EiSessionRepository.class)
            .updateEiSessionStatus(sessionId, status));
}
```

But my session is not updated as the jdbi is waiting for the open transaction to complete. Why *jdbi.useHandle* doesn't create new handle and execute requests, but wait for the transaction to complete? I want to use the new handle to update the session, not use the transaction in use